# one MP3 file not playing in Chrome (others do)

Tags: google-chrome, mp3, embed, html5-audio

I'm developing a Joomla-site (2.5) and embedded an audio file (mp3) in a K2-article using the html5-tags (see code below). The mp3 is playing perfectly in Firefox (vs 16.02) , IE (vs 8.0.6) but not in Google Chrome (vs. 23.0) . Strangely enough, the problem seems to be related to this particular mp3 file only, other mp3's are doing fine, both in Chrome, Firefox and IE.

```
<audio autoplay="autoplay" width="200" src="images/tonesound/mp3/01funkybeats.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls" preload="none"></audio>
```

The file is rather large (11.4 MB), after 15 seconds or so the music starts playing (in Firefox and IE, not in Chrome).

Comment: Post your file so we can see what's going on.  Better yet, post a link to the file as it is on your web server.

Comment: [link(http://www.workshops-tonesound.nl/) The player is in the sidebar on the right, controlling on/off. Normally the file would start loading immediately (the progress bar is showing this). Thnx for your help !!

Answer (score 0):

You [shouldn't use MP3 on the web](https://www.scirra.com/blog/64/why-you-shouldnt-use-mp3-in-your-html5-games).  The best solution is to encode all your audio to AAC and Ogg, since those two formats cover all browsers, whereas MP3 definitely won't work everywhere.

Comment: Okay, that's a start. I have no experience with audio files on the web whatsoever, so this sounds ;-) like a viable workaround. From a technical perspective though, I still wonder what's going on here. Thanx for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

Your MP3 file's first few frames are corrupt.  Try re-encoding the media.

You can see this with the debugging output in VLC.